# How do you parent Armature Bones and In what order?

Tags: armature, bones, parent

I'm pretty new to blender so do me gently. Right now my biggest hurdle is the rigging process. I've placed all of my bones using (shift+A) for the necessary stuff.. but realized that they're all separate from one another. Like they act like their independent from one another. For example I'm unable to select multiple bones. I made some kind of goof. I think it's because they aren't parented to each other. So how do I go about parenting bones and in what order? I hope that makes sense. There's a screenshot below to help illustrate. I really appreciate the input and i'll reply to any additional questions as quickly as I can.

Party on!

[image]

Comment: In my view, this question is much too broad. Even when discussing a single armature, how the various bones would be parented would depend upon a large number of factors, including exactly what movements are desired of the animation. And although this question illustrates a specific armature, details about what the animator would hope to accomplish are not provided. I favor closing the question as too broad, but am not prepared to be the first to vote to do so.

Comment: use CRTL+P to set parent. does that help?

Comment: could you please share your .blend file? to be able to assist you